# Put max character length on angular expression and add ellipses

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular expression which resolves to a block of text.

The block of text can be anywhere in size from 1 character to over 3,000. I want to add a limit to the amount of text which displays and hopefully add an ellipses to the end of the text, either with an image or somthing like `<div>...</div>`.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Is there an angular way to accomplish this, a filter of some sort perhaps?

Or would a directive be the better way to go?

```
<div text-length-limit>{{description}}</div>
```

Comment: @Appeiron _filter but directive_.... whut?

Comment: I think for trimming you better implement `filter` _instead of_ directive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with this:

```
{{description | limitTo: 5}}<span ng-show="description.length > 5">...</span>
```

`limitTo` limits the string to the desired length (5 here) and if the original string is upper that length display the `...` after first 5 characters.

Comment: Fantastic answer, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Filters are well suited for formatting a value to another value but keeping the same type.  In this case you want a filter that adds an ellipsis (...) if the length of the string is longer than a given length.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    app.filter('ellipsis', function() {
        return function(val, maxLength) {
           if (val && val.toString().length > maxLength) {
               return val.toString().substring(0, maxLength) + '...';
           }
           return val;
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  Type text longer than 5 characters: <input type="text" ng-model="text" /> {{text | ellipsis:5}}
</div>
```